# Throwing error while printing record element string?

Tags: record, ada

Throwing error while printing record element string using put why please help me to understand?

```ada
 with ada.text_io;
 use ada.text_io;

procedure main is
  type my_rec is record
    name:string(1..5)of integer; 
  end record;
var:my_rec;

begin
var.name:="hello";
put(var.name); -- why error?
end main;
```

error message is below

```ada
 cc -c hello.adb                                                                
 hello.adb:7:27: missing ";"                                                     
 gnatmake: "main.adb" compilation error
```

Comment: Ummm... what is `string(1..5) of integer`?

Comment: I will never understand this.  People get error messages, then they ask for help understanding the error message, but they don't actually show us what the message is but assume we can somehow read their screen from all the way over where we're sitting.

Comment: the error is "missing semicolon" right at `of integer;` ... go figure

Comment: @ajb sorry here is there error message       cc -c hello.adb                                                                
hello.adb:7:27: missing ";"                                                     
gnatmake: "main.adb" compilation error

Comment: I think `name` is supposed to be just `string(1..5)`.  I have no idea what `of integer` was trying to accomplish.  It definitely does not belong there.

Comment: @ajb ya thanks i got it integer was useless there

Comment: @ajb Can you please give a example how to use unbounded string i googled a lot and i m new to ada but was unable to find. what all i want is lets take my:string here i want to skip index so that any no of string can be stored?can u please show a small example?

Comment: Have you tried google "Ada unbounded string example"?  the first few hits have some useful examples, I recommend the Wikibook (second hit)

Comment: "Any number of strings", or "one string of any length"?

Answer (score 0):

`hello.adb:7:27` is the coordinates of the error, so take a look in "hello.adb" on line 7 at character position 27.